# Liquibase runs sqlFile change twice

Tags: liquibase

For some reason, Liquibase is running sql file twice, I do not understand why:

```
2021-05-04 12:17:50.341  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET @role_org_viewer_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_roles WHERE name='org_viewer')
2021-05-04 12:17:50.341  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET @role_domain_viewer_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_roles WHERE name='domain_viewer')
2021-05-04 12:17:50.341  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET @role_domain_editor_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_roles WHERE name='domain_editor')
2021-05-04 12:17:50.342  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET @role_domain_manager_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_roles WHERE name='domain_manager')
2021-05-04 12:17:50.342  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET @role_ep_admin = (SELECT id FROM auth_roles WHERE name='ep_admin')
2021-05-04 12:17:50.342  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET @perm_user_read_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_permissions WHERE resource_type='user' AND action='read')
2021-05-04 12:17:50.343  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET @perm_role_read_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_permissions WHERE resource_type='role' AND action='read')
2021-05-04 12:17:50.343  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET @perm_catalog_screen_view_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_permissions WHERE resource_type='catalog_screen' AND action='view')
2021-05-04 12:17:50.343  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET @perm_api_products_screen_view_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_permissions WHERE resource_type='api_products_screen' AND action='view')
2021-05-04 12:17:50.344  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET @perm_api_product_read_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_permissions WHERE resource_type='api_product' AND action='read')
2021-05-04 12:17:50.344  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET @perm_shared_schema_read_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_permissions WHERE resource_type='shared_schema' AND action='read')
2021-05-04 12:17:50.344  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET @perm_shared_event_read_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_permissions WHERE resource_type='shared_event' AND action='read')
2021-05-04 12:17:50.345  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : INSERT INTO auth_roles_to_permissions_assn (role_id, permission_id) VALUES (@role_org_viewer_id, @perm_user_read_id)
2021-05-04 12:17:50.345  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : INSERT INTO auth_roles_to_permissions_assn (role_id, permission_id) VALUES (@role_org_viewer_id, @perm_role_read_id)
2021-05-04 12:17:50.346  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : INSERT INTO auth_roles_to_permissions_assn (role_id, permission_id) VALUES (@role_org_viewer_id, @perm_catalog_screen_view_id)
2021-05-04 12:17:50.346  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : INSERT INTO auth_roles_to_permissions_assn (role_id, permission_id) VALUES (@role_org_viewer_id, @perm_api_products_screen_view_id)
2021-05-04 12:17:50.346  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : INSERT INTO auth_roles_to_permissions_assn (role_id, permission_id) VALUES (@role_org_viewer_id, @perm_api_product_read_id)
2021-05-04 12:17:50.346  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : INSERT INTO auth_roles_to_permissions_assn (role_id, permission_id) VALUES (@role_org_viewer_id, @perm_shared_schema_read_id)
2021-05-04 12:17:50.346  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : INSERT INTO auth_roles_to_permissions_assn (role_id, permission_id) VALUES (@role_org_viewer_id, @perm_shared_event_read_id)
2021-05-04 12:17:50.347  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet            : SQL in file sqlFiles/003_insert_roles_to_permissions_assn.sql executed
2021-05-04 12:17:50.347  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet            : ChangeSet db/changesets/206_insert_into_roles_to_permissions_assn.json::DATAGO-XXX-7::imochurad ran successfully in 9ms
2021-05-04 12:17:50.347  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : INSERT INTO maas.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, `DESCRIPTION`, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES ('DATAGO-XXX-7', 'imochurad', 'db/changesets/206_insert_into_roles_to_permissions_assn.json', NOW(), 173, '8:92cdcc74836d90921bd449bc56db79e9', 'sqlFile', 'DATAGO-XXX: Fine-grained RBAC', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '3.8.9', '0145070044')
2021-05-04 12:17:50.350  INFO [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET @role_org_viewer_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_roles WHERE name='org_viewer');
SET @role_domain_viewer_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_roles WHERE name='domain_viewer');
SET @role_domain_editor_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_roles WHERE name='domain_editor');
SET @role_domain_manager_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_roles WHERE name='domain_manager');
SET @role_ep_admin = (SELECT id FROM auth_roles WHERE name='ep_admin');

SET @perm_user_read_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_permissions WHERE resource_type='user' AND action='read');

SET @perm_role_read_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_permissions WHERE resource_type='role' AND action='read');

SET @perm_catalog_screen_view_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_permissions WHERE resource_type='catalog_screen' AND action='view');

SET @perm_api_products_screen_view_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_permissions WHERE resource_type='api_products_screen' AND action='view');

SET @perm_api_product_read_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_permissions WHERE resource_type='api_product' AND action='read');

SET @perm_shared_schema_read_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_permissions WHERE resource_type='shared_schema' AND action='read');

SET @perm_shared_event_read_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_permissions WHERE resource_type='shared_event' AND action='read');

INSERT INTO auth_roles_to_permissions_assn (role_id, permission_id) VALUES (@role_org_viewer_id, @perm_user_read_id);
INSERT INTO auth_roles_to_permissions_assn (role_id, permission_id) VALUES (@role_org_viewer_id, @perm_role_read_id);
INSERT INTO auth_roles_to_permissions_assn (role_id, permission_id) VALUES (@role_org_viewer_id, @perm_catalog_screen_view_id);
INSERT INTO auth_roles_to_permissions_assn (role_id, permission_id) VALUES (@role_org_viewer_id, @perm_api_products_screen_view_id);
INSERT INTO auth_roles_to_permissions_assn (role_id, permission_id) VALUES (@role_org_viewer_id, @perm_api_product_read_id);
INSERT INTO auth_roles_to_permissions_assn (role_id, permission_id) VALUES (@role_org_viewer_id, @perm_shared_schema_read_id);
INSERT INTO auth_roles_to_permissions_assn (role_id, permission_id) VALUES (@role_org_viewer_id, @perm_shared_event_read_id);
2021-05-04 12:17:50.353 ERROR [] 15667 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet            : Change Set db/changesets/sqlFiles/003_insert_roles_to_permissions_assn.sql::raw::includeAll failed.  Error: (conn=104) Duplicate entry '89711431716-89711431721' for key 'PRIMARY' [Failed SQL: (1062) SET @role_org_viewer_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_roles WHERE name='org_viewer');
```

I have a folder sqlFiles that is listing some of the files that I then reference in my changelogs. As you can see from the logs, this SQL file is being applied twice, once via the changelog file, which is being marked as EXECUTED and then it goes again.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that the folder `sqlFiles` was under
`"path": "classpath:/db/changesets"` and that caused it to run the same SQL file twice. Once from the changelog and once as an independent SQL file.